# Getting Null pointer Exception on Page Object page using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception

I am new for Selenium web driver.
I have tried to create Selenium web driver framework.but i have been stuck due to this null pointer exception.
I have created a Testcase class, Base class and a Page Object class.

TestCase Class: //Class name

```
package com.uiautomation.com.uiautomation.testscripts;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import com.uiautomation.base.LoginBase;
import com.uiautomation.setup.setBrowser;

public class LoginTest{
 WebDriver driver;
 setBrowser browser= new setBrowser();

  @BeforeClass
  public void beforeClass() {
      browser.setupwebdriver("FF");
  }

  @Test()
  public void loginPage() {
      LoginBase base = new LoginBase(driver);//create a new instance of Login base class
      base.loginToDummySite("Vishalbha", "abc123");//call base class method and pass parameters value
  }


  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
  }

}
```

base Class:

```
package com.uiautomation.base;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.uiautomation.pageobjects.LoginPO;

public class LoginBase {

     WebDriver driver;
    public LoginBase(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver= driver;
    }

    public void loginToDummySite(String UserName, String Password){
        System.out.println(UserName);
        LoginPO loginPO= new LoginPO(driver);// create instance of loginPO class
        loginPO.enterUserName(UserName);
        loginPO.enterPassword(Password);
        loginPO.loginButtonClick();
    }
}
```

Page object class:

```
package com.uiautomation.pageobjects;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPO {
    WebDriver driver;
    public LoginPO(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver= driver;
    }

    @FindBy(id = "username")
     private static WebElement userNameTextbox;

    @FindBy(id="password")
    private WebElement passwordTextbox;

    @FindBy(id="login")
    private WebElement loginButton;


    public void enterUserName(String UserName){
        userNameTextbox.clear();
        userNameTextbox.sendKeys(UserName);
    }
    public void enterPassword(String Password){
        passwordTextbox.clear();
        passwordTextbox.sendKeys(Password);
    }   
    public void loginButtonClick(){
        loginButton.click();
    }   

}
```

While executing my script then website open but "userNameTextbox" page object object getting error Null pointer exception.
I am using selenium web driver 2.53.0.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try with public static WebDriver driver; in all places

Comment: you have many problems in your code, but very first one is this: `@BeforeClass` must be static and is called before class was instantiated. And then inside that `@BeforeClass` method you are calling `browser`, which only instantiated when class is

Comment: thanks for reply kiril.

Comment: Can you please explain me with a example.

Comment: Thanks Murali for your reply. but as i know static is a keyword which is used to make any variable or method or class a unique value ,which is defined only once in a class.for example Collage name of all employees.